# Complex analysis: Show that there is no analytic function on $B(0,1)$ satisfying $\sqrt{|z|}\leq |f(z)| \leq \sqrt[3]{|z|}$ for all $z\in B(0,1)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that there is no analytic function on $B(0,1)$ satisfying $\sqrt{|z|}\leq |f(z)| \leq \sqrt[3]{|z|}$ for all $z\in B(0,1)$.

The symbol $B(0,1)$ means the open disk with radius $1$ centered at $0$.

I am not sure how to attack those kinds of questions.

Many thanks for any help with this!

Comment: Quick idea sketch: 1) $f(0) = 0$, 2) analytic functions have zeros of an integral order, $n$ 3) you should be able to show that $f/z^n$ is a "nicely behaved" function, 4) this should lead to a contradiction at $z=0$. (I left a lot of places for you to fill in with details.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(0)=0$ so there exists an anlaytic function $g$ in $B(0,1)$ such that $f(z)=zg(z)$. But then $\sqrt {|z|} \leq |z||g(z)$ which implies $|g(z)| \geq \frac 1 {\sqrt {|z|}} \to \infty$ as $z \to 0$, a contradiction.$